# Can we join 2 table valued functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join 2 table-valued functions using a common column returned by each function respectively.

I am trying to do something like this :

```
Select * from function1(),function2() where id=1;
```

When I do this I get the error saying the column is ambigiuos as it is present in both the set of columns retuned.

How can I join these 2 table-valued functions?

Answer (score 2):

You can.  But as with anything else in the `from` clause, table valued functions need to given aliases.  And:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.

So:

```
select *
from function1() f1 join
     function2() f2
     on f1.id = f2.id;
```

Comment: Can I use CROSS APPLY in this case?? If yes, then can someone provide the query ??

Comment: @AmaanKhan . . . If you have a question about `APPLY`, then ask that in *another* question.  This question is about `JOIN` (quite explicitly) and it has been answered.